# Detecting cron tasks run by another user

Tags: cron, privileges

I am currently working through the [Nebula challenges](http://exploit-exercises.com/nebula) on [exploit-exercises.com](http://exploit-exercises.com), and [one of the challenges](http://exploit-exercises.com/nebula/level03) relies on a script being run by cron.

This is run by another user (flag03) and the user I am logged in as (level03) doesn't have privileges to run `crontab -u flag03` to view the job.

The hint clearly indicates the script is run by cron. Additionally, it is the only script in the `/home/flag03` directory, so we would likely investigate further.

However, if this was the real world, I wouldn't know that this script was being run by cron.

Therefore the question is, how would I detect that the task was being run from the perspective of an unprivileged user?

I have tried the following:

```
while true; do ps au | grep <scriptname> | grep -v grep; done;
```

This allows me to see processes that run for a significant length of time, but not ones that exit almost immediately. It also presumes I know the name of the script.

The specific environment is Ubuntu. I can't use apt-get, but I have access to gcc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you look at anything under `/var/log/`? Look for log messages about cron tasks.

Comment: No, unfortunately no permissions or not relevant (grep -ri cron / or find / -name cron)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Ubuntu? If it's using `systemd`, you could rely on the `cron` cgroup created by `systemd` I guess, as all processes started by `cron` will be a direct child.

One of the option to get this information is to use the ps command with something like:

```
ps -eo user,pid,cmd,unit | grep cron.service | grep flag03
```

Comment: Why does this not suffer from the same issue as the suggestion in the question i.e. short lived processes will be missed.

Comment: Indeed, but you could mix that with the idea from @piroux and add a inotify watch on the files in `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/cron.service/`

Comment: `inotify` won't work on those files, but a busy loop starting one second before each minute that watches the contents of `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/cron.service/cgroup.procs` and retrieves the corresponding command line from `/proc/pid/cmdline` should be able to capture the commands, especially if you slow down everything by allocating a lot of RAM to evict most things from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The closest you can get is:

```
inotifywait -m /home/flag03/script
```

That won't show execution but it will show when `script` is opened or accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using inotifywait in the /proc/[0-9]+ directories would let you have a better glimpse of short run processes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the challenge this method of attack would assume that you can run a script and watch what runs on the box, so I would write a script that simply does a dump of `ps -eaf` every couple of seconds, this would catch a cron, eventually, since crons run once every minute.

This vector of attack would require you to watch for this script running, note the location of the script, and dig in deeper.

Comment: Isn't that pretty much the one-liner I posted in the question?

Comment: @Cybergibbons - more or less. I'd modify the script slightly and there are other ways to watch for processes running, so if this wasn't successful in finding any cronjobs, I might dig in deeper with those.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the file is located on `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/flag03`, and you can read it with the `nebula` account.

But `level03` doesn't have enough privileges to access it.

Answer (score -1):

```
while true; do ps aux | egrep -v "grep|tail|aux" | tail -n 1; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Give more info, it is a Q&A site and not a snippet sharing one.